processRowPostCreate is not working when grid is expanded or scrolled
I want to add custom attribute ( in my case data-ref ) to the cells on my ag-grid tables. I am using processRowPostCreate method from ag-grid and it is working but when I expand my table or scroll down, this attribute is not available on the cells.
It looks like this method add attribute to only visible cell on the application start. How can I make sure when all the cells gets this attribute?
What i am trying to do is that basically not to use cellRenderer to add custom attribute.
For example I use getBusinessKeyForNode to add custom attribute to the rows which is working perfectly ( in case it add 'row-business-key' instead of data-ref which is okey for me.
Anyone knows if there is a built-in function which behave like it but for cells ?
